# Create a popup "a new version of this app is available"

Tags: iphone, app-store

I would like to display a popup in my iPhone app that alert users when a new version is available in the appstore with a direct link to the iTunes page of the app.

Do you know how can I implement that?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the version in the app in a file or something.  Then, store the latest version number on a server somewhere.  When the app launches, see if they match.

Answer (score 0):

you can checkout https://github.com/nicklockwood/iVersion for how to ask the appStore which version is on the store.